# why is the .helper function not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

ok so every time I try to run this, my browser is saying that "helpers is not defined. What am I doing wrong here? (sorry for the formatting btw, new to this platform)

this is the html side:

```
<head>
<title>blueSlipGang</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{> postForm}}
 {{> postList}}
</body>

<template name= "postList">
<ul>
  {{#each posts}}
  <li>{{content}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>

<template name= "postForm">
<form>
  <textarea id=content required></textarea>
  <button type="submit">say</button>
</form>
</template>
```

and this is the JavaScript file:

```
Post = new Mongo.Collection('post');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.postList.helpers({
posts: function(){
  return Post.find();
  }
});

 Template.postForm.events({
'submit form': function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
 }
 })
}
```

Comment: Your helper is named `posts` while the HTML template calls `each post`

Comment: wait, isn't the "posts" just the name of the function.

Comment: Yes but you are not calling this helper function. You wrote `{{#each post}}` but `post` is not defined, it's `posts`, that is defined in helpers. So you need to change either `posts` to `post` or `{{#each post}}` to `{{#each posts}}`

Comment: just tried it, it still didn't work and gave me the same error. I just don't know why it's not working, and the code isn't even running in my browser.